# ActiveRecord find query with join only doesn't include data from joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, find

I have two tables: keyword_reports and keywords (with relevant AR models).

keyword_reports has a keyword_id column, which I'm using to join the keywords table like so:

```
KeywordReport.find(:all, :joins => :keyword, :conditions => {:page_id => 10})
```

which correctly pulls back records for keyword_reports, but doesn't include the data from the joined keyword table.

I looked at the log to see the generated SQL and it is doing:

```
SELECT `keyword_reports`.* from...
```

instead of:

```
SELECT * from ...
```

which it needs to do in order for me to get all the data. When I manually edit the SQL to format as desired, sure enough, it grabs all the data. I've tried using :includes and :select to no avail.

How do I prevent the query from limiting results only to the first table?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it using:

```
:select => '*'
```

In my case this works, just be cautious of columns with the same name in the tables. I think only one of the columns will be available. To solve this you can use:

```
:select => '*, tbl1.field as field1, tbl2.field as field2'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

think you probably had a typo.  `:include` (no s) should do it.

`KeywordReport.find(:all, :include => :keyword, :conditions => {:page_id => 10})`

This assumes that you have the relationship setup in the model

```
#KeywordReport
belongs_to :keyword
```

Hope this puts you one the right track

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply. The relationship is actually reverse. 

    #Keyword
    has_many :keyword_reports

    #KeywordReport
    belongs_to :keyword

Based on that, I don't think :include will help me. The generated SQL is two statements with the above suggestion, and they don't perform a join. The second statement just tries to find keyword records using the IN operator from keyword_id's returned from the keyword_reports result set.

Perhaps I'm missing something so any further advice is appreciated.